# Difference between graph.add() and dataset.add() in RDFLib library, python

Tags: python, rdf, semantic-web, rdflib

My question is: what is the difference between dataset.add() and graph.add() in rdflib for python. I was working under the assumption that graph.add was used for the object type properties and dataset.add was for the data type properties. However I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

- graph.add() adds a triple to a graph,
- dataset.add() adds a triple to the default graph, or a quad to a dataset

Example from http://rdflib.readthedocs.io [1]:

Create a new Dataset

`ds = Dataset()`

simple triples goes to default graph

`ds.add((URIRef('http://example.org/a'),URIRef('http://www.example.org/b'),Literal('foo')))`

Create a graph in the dataset, if the graph name has already been used, the corresponding graph will be returned (ie, the Dataset keeps track of the constituent graphs)

`g = ds.graph(URIRef('http://www.example.com/gr'))`

add triples to the new graph as usual

`g.add((URIRef('http://example.org/x'),URIRef('http://example.org/y'),Literal('bar')))`

alternatively: add a quad to the dataset -> goes to the graph

`ds.add((URIRef('http://example.org/x'),URIRef('http://example.org/z'),Literal('foo-bar'),g))`

It has nothing to do with whether something is an object property or a datatype property.

[1] http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html?highlight=dataset#rdflib.graph.Dataset